# Fetching data from another contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

I have the two following contracts: `tryContract` and `testData`. The `testData` contract aims at fetching data from the `tryContract` contract utilizing its `get_attributes` function. Before doing any fetching, assume I fill in the map in the `tryContract` contract using the following inputs:

```
["0x0","0x1","0x2","0x3","0x4","0x5","0x6","0x7","0x8","0x9"]

pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract tryContract {
    mapping (address=>bytes32[10]) Map;

    function fill_map(bytes32[10] _attributes) public  {
            Map[msg.sender] = _attributes;
    }

    function get_attributes(address _id) view public returns (bytes32[10]){
      return Map[_id];
    }
}

contract testData {
    address Address;
    //function takes address of user as input
    function get_address (address _Address) constant{   
        Address = _Address;
    } 

    bytes32[10] Data;
    //function takes the address of previous contract as input
    function fetch(address _try_Adress) public view returns (bytes32[10]) {
        tryContract r = tryContract(_try_Adress);
        Data = r.get_attributes(Address);
        return (Data);
    }
}
```

After running the code and trying to fetch the data stored, the output I receive is incorrect. The output is:

```
["0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0","0x0"]
```

Why does it not recognize the data that had been previously stored in the map?

Comment: Your get_attributes function is returning staff[_id] but your mapping object is called Map. Are you trying to return Map[_id]?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I fixed it now.

Comment: Did this fix your output?

Comment: No, but I think I found the fix. The function "get_address" was declared as constant. Once that was removed, the data was fetched properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion in the `testData`. The function `get_address` has been defined as `constant` but is changing the state (so it should be a *set* instead) and the Address is used into the `fetch` to get the data.

```
function fetch(address _try_Adress) public view returns (bytes32[10]) {
    tryContract r = tryContract(_try_Adress);
    Data = r.get_attributes(Address);
    return (Data);
}
```

you can use this which is equivalent and you don't need the `get_address` (in case will work properly) to be called before the `fetch`

```
function fetch(address _try_Adress) public view returns (bytes32[10]) {
    tryContract r = tryContract(_try_Adress);

    return r.get_attributes(msg.sender);
}
```

another way might be to fix the `get_address` function (which I called `set_address` in this case)

```
function set_address (address _Address) public {   
    Address = _Address;
} 

function fetch(address _try_Adress) public view returns (bytes32[10]) {
    tryContract r = tryContract(_try_Adress);

    return r.get_attributes(Address);
}
```

I suggest the first approach since you will avoid one call.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `constant` from `get_address` function.

```
function get_address (address _Address){   
        Address = _Address;
    }
```